# Drupal 6 - Flush all Caches not emptying all cache tables in DB

Tags: database, drupal-6, cache-control

I've tried clicking "Clear cached data" in Performance settings, and also running "drush cc all", but some cache tables always have some rows left in them:

- cache_form always has 37 rows left (and that is a lot of data)
- cache_location always has 1 row left
- cache_update always has 3 rows left

I want to completely empty all my cache tables before I take a db dump and transfer it from my development box to my production server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not in depth familiar with those cache tables. But the most obvious reason would be that the cache is created after the cache is cleared.

To solve your problem you could manually delete the content in the tables with drush or some other tool to connect to your database. You could also leave out the contents of those tables, like the backup migrate does by default with all cache tables, watchdog etc.

Comment: I decided to start using the backup and migrate module along with drush for taking all my db dumps, as it skips all cache tables etc, and this turned out to be a great move - smaller, faster dumps, and it got rid of all the weird cache behaviour i was experiencing when moving a db dump from dev to prod. I couldnt find any good docs on using drush with backup and migrate, so I did a blog post about it: http://www.only10types.com/2011/03/drush-backup-and-migrate-command.html